# How to get Assembly when loading assembly using mono_assembly_load_from?

Tags: c#, mono, dllimport, .net-4.8

I load assemblies into the application using Mono methods. The problem is that when I load the assembly I get only `IntPtr`, but I need `System.Reflection.Assembly`. How to get it using `IntPtr`?

Methods I import and use:

```csharp
public static class MonoCalls {
    [DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint = "mono_image_open_from_data")]
    public static extern IntPtr MonoImageOpenFromData(IntPtr dataHandle, int dataLenght, bool shouldCopy, IntPtr status);

    [DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint = "mono_assembly_load_from")]
    public static extern IntPtr MonoAssemblyLoadFrom(IntPtr imageHandle, string name, IntPtr status);
}
```

Class for loading an assembly into memory (the input is an assembly as an array of bytes):

```csharp
public class Mono {
    IntPtr Image;
    IntPtr Assembly;
    public IntPtr Activate(byte[] Bytes) {
        unsafe {
            fixed (byte* Pointer = Bytes) {
                Image = MonoCalls.MonoImageOpenFromData((IntPtr)Pointer, Bytes.Length, true, IntPtr.Zero);
                Assembly = MonoCalls.MonoAssemblyLoadFrom(Image, string.Empty, IntPtr.Zero);
                return Assembly;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main code:

```csharp
...

Mono Mono = new();
byte[] Assembly_Bytes = ...; // Assembly
IntPtr Pointer = Mono.Activate(Assembly_Bytes);
string MyAssemblyName = "MyAssembly";

Assembly FoundAssembly;
foreach (Assembly Assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
    if (Assembly.GetName().Name.Equals(MyAssemblyName)) {
        FoundAssembly = Assembly; // Got it (or an assembly with similar name)
        return;
    }
}

Type[] Types = FoundAssembly.GetTypes(); // Main purpose of this part of code
...
```

Is there any method like `GetAssemblyByPtr(IntPtr)` that returns `System.Reflection.Assembly`?

*Simple `Assembly.Load()` not suitable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading an assembly I bind to the assembly loading event, in the event I receive the assembly. After loading, the event is unbinded.

Main code:

```csharp
...
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad;
...
// Loading assemblies
// It's supposed to load only the assemblies I need at the moment.
...
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad -= CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad;
...
```

```csharp
private void CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad(object Sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs AssemblyLoadEventArgs) {
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentDomain_AssemblyLoad");
    Assembly MyAssembly = AssemblyLoadEventArgs.LoadedAssembly;
    // Got loaded assembly (or assemblies)
}
```